# Azure Architecture Design

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to Azure, and a little confused about blob storage.  I have a need for clients to access via FTP / SFTP to push and pull files (XML, CSV, EDI, etc).  The pushed files are read in by a .net application and written to a database.  As I understand, we would use a VM role to create a FTP / SFTP server, a worker role to execute the .net code, SQL Storage for the DB and Blob storage for the files.

Am I correct in this assumption first, and second can a VM role attach a storage blob for writing and reading files and can a worker role attach to the same storage blob to read and write files as well.

Sample:

client pushed xml file to VM via FTP.  VM writes XML file to storage.  Worker role reads file, processes it and writes contents to db.

Is my thinking correct or am I missing the boat?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given Azure has an array of services so you have a few options. One important thing to keep in mind with Azure is that your **worker roles**, which are simply Windows Server 2008 without IIS installed, are very flexible so there is a lot you can do with them – this includes writing your own FTP server and being able to host it via a worker role VMs. The [FTP to Azure Blob Storage Bridge](http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/) (on CodePlex) solution is an example of this.

In addition, you could use a **web role** (which is the same as a worker role but with IIS enabled) to do the same - so rather than rolling your own FTP server you can use IIS. [A visual guide to setting IIS up to run as an FTP server](http://www.itq.nl/blogs/post/Walkthrough-Hosting-FTP-on-IIS-75-in-Windows-Azure-VM.aspx) in Azure can be found on ITQ.
I’d recommend doing some further reading to determine which is the better option of the two. Also have a think about you requirements as this may influence your approach, i.e. scaling, bandwidth, costs, your preferred deployment model etc.

As far as storing the files goes you can certainly use Blob Storage. If you have no need for a relational database in your system then you could skip using SQL Azure altogether (in which case the web role solution referenced above won’t be of much use) – but again that comes down to your particular requirements.

The [official Windows Azure website](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/) is a good source of knowledge, especially if you’re getting started, so do take the time to look through some of the pertinent documentation.

Comment: Thanks Bern,  The reason we were thinking VM is because we need to host several protocols (SFTP, FTP, FTPS, HTTPS) and currently use a third party server for this rather than roll our own.  Im still unclear though, can a VM role talk to a some kind of file object, wether that be a storage blog, etc that a worker role can as well?  I need a central repository for files that all roles can access and read and write to.  Wether that be directly mounting from the VM or writing a .net app to handle the transfer from local to the storage object is what we were thinking.

Comment: Hi @user2136241 - yes you're correct, the blob storage APIs are very flexible and you can use blob storage as a file system of sorts (blobs = files / blob containers = folders). If you have the time take a moment to look at this article on Azure: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/ it might give you a more comprehensive overview of blob storage.