# How to upload a file to Azure Storage with WinSCP (SFTP)?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, sftp, winscp

theI have a C# service using WinSCP which reliably uploads files to any SFTP server. I'd like to use it to connect to MS Azure Storage and **upload** files there using the same SFTP protocol. ***Please note I am not looking to use any other protocol (i.e.: FTP, FTPS, HTTPS, etc.) as well as I am not looking to SFTP files [out] of the Azure Storage.*** There are plenty of examples of  how to use WinSCP when SFTP [out] from Azure Storage but none of them covers how to SFTP [in].

I have searched Stack Overflow knowledge base, Azure Help Documentation (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) as well as WinSCP docs (http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_webjob_sftp, etc.).

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE: 2016-01-29**
So... from what I understand so far, it is not possible to upload files to Azure Storage using SFTP protocol. MS Azure does not support this feature. Can anybody confirm that for me please?

**UPDATE: 2016-02-01**
The similar Q/A here ([Facading Azure storage blob with sFTP service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711592/facading-azure-storage-blob-with-sftp-service)) does not answer my question because:
a) all answers are suggesting a theoretical workarounds using VM or other substitutes
b) it does not provide clear answer to my question

**This should not be so difficult to answer.** If the SFTP is not supported then the answer is: ***"SFTP is not supported in Azure"***. If the SFTP protocol is supported, then please provide more details about the settings, methods, and/or C# example. My question is clearly defined on purpose so others with the same need can quickly find the answer without wasting their time.

Answer (score -1):

From your comments, it seems that you were already given the SFTP access information. As such, your question is not about Azure specifically. All you ask for is how to upload to an SFTP. For that use any SFTP upload example on the WinSCP site. For instance, the very basic example [Uploading a single file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_single_file). Just use the access information you were given by the client.

---

Though again, I'm not sure there's an SFTP access to Azure Storage. But that's something you have to discuss with the client. They insist on the SFTP.

For discussion about remote access to Azure Storage, see for example:

- [Get started with Azure File storage on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files)
- [Facading Azure storage blob with sFTP service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21711592/850848)

None of these mention any SFTP. Actually Azure services do not support SFTP in general. SFTP is *nix thing generally. Azure services run of Windows. There's no SFTP in Windows ([yet](https://serverfault.com/q/648855/168875)). Windows supports an FTPS. But Azure Store does not seem to support that either.

Maybe there's some misunderstanding. Maybe it's not the Azure Storage, maybe it's just an Azure Linux box used to store files. Or they mean the FTPS, not the SFTP. They might have an Azure VM with an FTPS server to access the Azure Storage.